# Strange stamp on gettimeofday()

Tags: c, gettimeofday

I have written this code for a sampling assignment at my university.

```
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    struct timeval tv;

    float t = atoi(argv[1]);  //sampling time period in sec's
    float dt = atoi(argv[2]);   //sampling rate in msec's
    double time;
    int nsamples = t/dt * 1000; //number of samples floored

    //samples storage array
    double *samples;
    samples = malloc(nsamples);

    printf("%d\n\n",nsamples);

    int c = 0;  //array index
    double divergance;

    gettimeofday(&tv, NULL);
    time =(double) tv.tv_sec + tv.tv_usec / 1000000.0f;
    samples[c] = time;
    printf("time: %f\n", samples[c]);

    usleep(dt * 1000);

    while(c<nsamples){
      c++;

      gettimeofday(&tv, NULL);
      time = (double) tv.tv_sec + tv.tv_usec / 1000000.0f;
      samples[c] = time;

      //divergance calculated in msec's
      divergance = (samples[c] - samples[c-1]);
      if (c==9){
        printf("%f \n \n%f", samples[c-1], samples[c]);
      }
      printf("time: %f\ndivergance: %f ms\n\n", samples[c], divergance*1000);

      usleep(dt *1000);
    }

}
```

and this is my output

> time: 1557335682.435666 divergance: 200.127125 ms
>
> time: 1557335682.635813 divergance: 200.146914 ms
>
> time: 1557335682.835952 divergance: 200.139046 ms
>
> time: 1557335683.036075 divergance: 200.123072 ms
>
> time: 1557335683.236192 divergance:
>   -50328976507548121002151598324465532616014103321089770750300716493231241208217866953937760599346823570331739493744117764925654540012842402655523878795775819489233146901362588461216017208320541658368563434403808909221817741213696.000000 ms
>
> time: 1557335683.436400 divergance: 1557335683436.399902 ms
>
> time: 1557335683.636521 divergance: 1557335683636.520752 ms
>
> time: 1557335683.836647 divergance: 1557335683836.646973 ms

Does anyone understand what's that weird output there on the fifth calculation. I can not imagine any logical explanation as I have not encountered any similar "bug" before. Does it have to do with some certain feature of `gettimeofday()` function?

Νote: the input is `10` and `200`

Comment: You have `while(c<nsamples){ c++; ` so perhaps `samples[c]` breaks the array. I suggest starting with `c = 1` and incrementing at the *end* of the loop, or some similar adjustment.

Comment: `samples = malloc(nsamples)` --> `samples = malloc(nsamples * sizeof(*samples))`

Comment: @dbush thank you very much. it worked. could you explain why?

Comment: @GiannisGonidelis I've added an answer detailing this.

Comment: The time that gets printed is correct, so the problem is apparently not related to gettimeofday.

Comment: Sorry, why do you mix `float` with `double` floating point values?  Do you fear of running out of stack space on declaring two `float` variables instead of declaring them `double`?  If you are trying to save stack space, probably you have not got that you are making the compiler to consider a large amount of automatic conversions from `double` to `float` and viceversa.  And worse, loss of precision when truncating values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't allocated enough space for `samples`:

```
samples = malloc(nsamples);
```

The `malloc` function allocates space for the specified number of **bytes**, not the number of array elements.  So your array is much shorter that you think it is.  This means you'll eventually write past the end of the array, invoking [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

You need to multiply the number of elements by the element size to allocate the correct amount of space:

```
samples = malloc(nsamples * sizeof(*samples));
```

You also have an off-by-one error when accessing the array:

```
int c = 0;
...
while(c<nsamples){
  c++;
  ...
  samples[c] = time;
  ...
}
```

This will also write past the end of the array, specifically one array element too many.

Change the loop to start with the value 1 and increment at the end.

```
int c = 0;
...
c = 1;
while(c<nsamples){
  ...
  samples[c] = time;
  ...
  c++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The parameter to `malloc(3)` mus be the number of **bytes** to allocate, not the number of samples.  If you plan to allocate an array of `float` or `double` samples, you had better to multiply that number by the `sizeof (float)` (or `sizeof (double)`) before passing the parameter to `malloc(3)`.  As `samples` is defined as a pointer to `double`, then you should use:

```
samples = malloc(nsamples * sizeof(double));
```

or better (if you happen to change the declaration of `samples`):

```
samples = malloc(nsamples * sizeof *samples);
```